# Access violation on sqlite3_open API call

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sqlite

I am writing a server application with sqlite3 and c++. My problem occurs in the following line: `int connect = _sqlite3_open(database_sqlite_file, &db);`

In the MSVC++ logs I get these notes:

`Unhandled exception at 0x74ABCB49 in Fantasia_Database.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.`

Anyone know the source of this error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely, `database_sqlite_file` is `NULL`.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html Go through the article and understand these concepts. Before this line print the "database_sqlite_file" and "db" variable.

Comment: "**executing** location 0x00000000" doesn't look good.

Comment: Have you called `sqlite3_initialize()`?

Comment: @n.m. This is not needed.

Comment: @CL It depends on how the lib was compiled.

Comment: IgorTandetnik: database_sqlite_file = C:\\FantasiaMMORPG\\Core\\Database\\game.sqlite

MantoshKumar: Can't print db as its an arbitrary variable